# Is "credit_balance" whitelisted feature on Facebook?

Tags: facebook, api, whitelist, facebook-rest-api

I've been storming the internet for information on how to obtain "credit_balance" from Facebook user.

To get user credit_balance, I'm using: [Facebook Credits - Getting error code 13 when trying to get credit balance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6563678/facebook-credits-getting-error-code-13-when-trying-to-get-credit-balance)

I'm aware of the fact that you have to use "application access_token" instead of user's one (I've been trying both tokens lately just to be sure).

And I'm fully aware of multiple posts which are saying that getting "credit_balance" is whitelisted feature.

So my conclusion is, that our app has not been whitelisted yet, that's why I'm receiving "Exception: 13: The underlying FQL query made by this API call has encountered the following error: credit_balance is not a member of the user table." exceptions ... so it should be end of story ... but, one of the Facebook officials told me, that "credit_balance" IS NOT whitelisted feature. Now I'm confused...

My two questions:

(1)
So where the truth lies? Please, can someone confirm or refute whether "obtaining credit_balance" from Facebook is whitelisted feature and that I have to undergone the whitelisting procedure which begins with filling the form here: https://www.facebook.com/help/contact_us.php?id=157379954315015
And then wait for the eternity to get whitelisted (obviously, we've already asked to get whitelisted...). (I'm also aware of fact that after whitelisting you have to re-authenticate your users, done that as well, still no luck.)

(2)
Also is there any chance how to check whether my application is whitelisted?

Thank you in advance

- Jakub

Answer (score 1):

Finally, an official answer. Our application has been whitelisted for: frictionless payments, get_balance (== get_credits == credit_balance), and gamer_status.

So if anybody has problem with "getting number of facebook credits", be sure you are whitelisted first.

Facebook whitelisted us after about 1.5month, so you should apply for "whitelisting" as soon as you start your project + you should be kicking (with all respect) Facebook to reply you as soon as possible.

Jakub

Comment: Another advice, Facebook sent us this "official answer" at least week after we had been whitelisted, so you should regularly check for yourself whether "get_balance" goes through or not.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the specific answer to your question, but I know that the Facebook API keeps changing rapidly, and so many of the posts/guides on the internet are outdated.

Also, a quick look on the [official Facebook credit API page](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/creditsapi/) yields the following:

> This whitelisted feature is an API call that allows an application to
>   determine a user's balance. It is only available to developers who
>   have designated Credits as their in-game currency. You can apply here.
>
> Please Note: This feature is currently only available through the old
>   PHP SDK. You also must re-authenticate the user after whitelisting,
>   before making the function call.

Perhaps the note is relevant to you?

Comment: Thanks for the comment! That's exactly what I've found as well, so I think it is true. But one guy from Facebook told me that just "determining credit_balance" should not be whitelist feature. That's why I got confused. Also I hope that somebody who has recent direct experience with Facebook API answers this... basicly I would like to hear "I've done 'credit_balance' in my app recently and YES/NO, it IS/ISN'T whitelist feature". But thank you for the answer nevertheless!